# Camera Preview crashes when starting the activity

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I'm trying to display a camera preview on a gingerbread 2.3.3 phone. But my application crashes on the device every time the activity starts.

Here's my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/loadbtn"
  android:src="@drawable/loadbtn"
  android:layout_width="50dp"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:layout_margin="10dp"
 />

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/capturebtn"
  android:src="@drawable/capturebtn"
  android:layout_width="50dp"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:layout_margin="10dp"
 />

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/editbtn"
  android:src="@drawable/editbtn"
  android:layout_width="50dp"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:layout_margin="10dp"
 />

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/closebtn"
  android:src="@drawable/closebtn"
  android:layout_width="50dp"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:layout_margin="10dp"
  android:onClick="backToStart"
 />

</LinearLayout>

 <SurfaceView
  android:id="@+id/camerapreview"
  android:layout_width="300dp"
  android:layout_height="300dp"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
  />
```

And my code:

```
public class PhotoHome extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

Camera camera;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean previewing = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_home);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
     surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
     surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();  
     surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

}

public void backToStart(View v)
{
    finish();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
         int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(previewing){
         camera.stopPreview();
         previewing = false;
        }

        if (camera != null){
            Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

            if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
            {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(height, width);                           
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            }

            if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
            {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);                           
            }

            if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180)
            {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(height, width);               
            }

            if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270)
            {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
            }

            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            try 
            {           
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);          
                camera.startPreview();
                previewing = true;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Error", "Cannot start preview", e);    
            }
        }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera = Camera.open();
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }


}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if (camera != null) {
         camera.stopPreview();
         camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
         camera.release();
         camera = null;
        }
}
```

Here's my permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

I'm trying to display the camera preview at a certain 300 x 300 area in the screen. But as I said the app crashes on the device, but it seems in the emulator, it is working because of the white background in the 300 x 300 area. Any ideas?

UPDATE: Logcat

```
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
   02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1070)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at com.example.photoexpress.PhotoHome.surfaceChanged(PhotoHome.java:77)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:558)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:350)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644) 
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6905)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6905)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6905)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1895)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1542)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1269)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1883)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3737)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:660)
    02-20 23:59:34.969: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365): [Blue Error Handler] Make Debugging Report file for main
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1070)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at com.example.photoexpress.PhotoHome.surfaceChanged(PhotoHome.java:77)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:558)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:350)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6905)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6905)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6905)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1895)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1542)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1269)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1883)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3737)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:660)
    02-20 23:59:34.979: E/AndroidRuntime(15365):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

On my Logcat it is said that I have an set parameters failed at this line. camera.setParameters(parameters); I've used this code to set camera preview as a background for a game. But I don't really know what happened and now it won't work. :(

Comment: please post your logcat !

Comment: I can't directly run my app while connected to my laptop since I have no usb driver for my android phone (LG). That's why I'm just transferring the .apk file to my device and install it to test my app. No logcat for me when deployed in device.

Comment: if your phone rooted then go to android market and download adb via wifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives error because, i think you are trying to set an invalid preview size .

See Roman Nurik answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2052927/1376688)

Comment: I think not, because I have no invalid preview size requested in my LogCat

Comment: some devices just ignore that line. Did you try to fix it? Try this at least http://stackoverflow.com/a/9126857/1376688

Comment: I tried placing the code on in the surfacechanged but the next problem is that the camera is displaying landscape.