# App crashes while changing rotation of camera

Tags: android

i want to implement camera preview app .when I'll test on emulator then it works fine .but when I'll test on real device(eg nexes) then it crash while on rotation change,and also can't able to select image from gallery but it works fine on emulator 
 my logcat is

```
    02-11 15:11:39.895: W/dalvikvm(8326): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception   
    (group=0x41542ba8)          
    02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326): Process: com.photostikers, PID: 8326
    02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
    02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at    
     android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native    Method)
   02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at  
    android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1650)   
   02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at 
   com.photostikers.Preview.surfaceChanged(Preview.java:159)                        
   02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at 
     android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:583)
   02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at  
    android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
   02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at  
    android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)     
   02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at 
   android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
   02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at 
   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1871)
   02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at 
   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
   02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at  android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
 02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at 
 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)   
 02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at  
  android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
 02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at 
  android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
 02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at 
  android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
  02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at 
  android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at 
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
  02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native 
  Method)
 02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at  
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):at    
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-11 15:11:39.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8326):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046523/runtimeexception-on-camera-setparameters-on-nexus-one

Comment: thanks rob for replying but my another problem is i can't add image from gallery in app by real device but it works fine on emulator or some other devices.but on some devices like nexes it crash

Comment: Difficult to know with seeing specifics...

Comment: i'm using Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
     photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
     startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 0);using this code. it gives crash on nexus 5 so let me know what the exact problem is? any help is appriciable....