# CameraSource cannot autofocus despite changing preview size

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I am trying to use a barcode reader by implementing a CameraSource, and by doing so, I no longer am able to autofocus on devices that should be able to do so.

```
cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, detector).setAutoFocusEnabled(true).build();
```

I used this, but then the logcat shouted at me:

```
I/CameraSource: Camera auto focus is not supported on this device.
```

So, I dig around on stackoverflow like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890381/camera-setparameters-failed-in-android), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23553445/android-auto-focus-when-continuous-auto-focus-modes-are-not-supported) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247483/setparameters-fails-despite-setting-preview-size).  At the end here is what I have:

```
FrameLayout cameraFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.welcome_camera);
    if (cameraFrame != null) {
        cameraFrame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Field[] declaredFields = CameraSource.class.getDeclaredFields();

                for (Field field : declaredFields) {
                    if (field.getType() == Camera.class) {
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        try {
                            Camera camera = (Camera) field.get(cameraSource);
                            if (camera != null) {
                                Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                                for (Camera.Size size : params.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
                                    Log.d("Sizes", size.height + " and width " + size.width);
                                }
                                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
                                camera.setParameters(params);
                            }
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        cameraFrame.addView(preview);
    }
```

I want to know the sizes, so that for the xml I can change the sizes.  The size is also confirmed from the `surfaceChanged` function here:
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

```
    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        cameraSource.stop();
    } catch (Exception e){
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }
    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here
    Log.d("Camerapreview", "h = " + h + " w = " + w);
    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        cameraSource.start(holder);
    } catch (SecurityException s) {
        Log.d(TAG, "shouldn't be here as permission should have been acquired by the main thread");
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

from the camera preview class.

However, the code above leads to RuntimeException for setParameters failed at the line `camera.setParameters(params);`.  I also tried `FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE` but that does not help.