# Releasing the camera: "Method called after release()" exception

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I'm trying to incorporate some camera-related features in my app. I open the camera manually and get the preview stream with `setPreviewCallback` and `startPreview`. I do *not* use the surface for displaying preview, but I do set it to comply with the Camera API docs. This is how I open the camera:

```
public Camera openCamera(int id)
{
    m_openedCamera = Camera.open(id);
    m_surfaceHolder = new SurfaceView(MyApplication.instance().getApplicationContext()).getHolder();
    Assert.assertNotNull(m_openedCamera);
    m_openedCamera.setPreviewDisplay(m_surfaceHolder);
    m_openedCameraFacing = facing;
    if (m_openedCamera != null)
        m_openedCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
    m_openedCamera.startPreview();
}
```

And this is how I release it, nothing fancy here:

```
public void releaseCamera()
{
    if (m_openedCamera != null)
    {
        m_openedCamera.stopPreview();
        m_openedCamera.release();
        m_openedCamera = null;
    }
}
```

It kinda works at first, but as I release the camera, I get an exception "Method called after release()".
To clarify: I do *not* call any camera methods after the camera has been released. Double and triple-checked under debugger that I don't. I think there's a mix of synchronous and asynchronous calls here that causes the problem.

Comment: checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8003222/1288725) if it helps, the problem may get solved if you add `mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);` in your code as stated in answer.

Comment: @MehulJoisar: please read my question carefully and realize I have no surface or holder whatsoever.

Comment: Using no preview surface (or its OpenGL equivalent) is illegal and may lead to different problems on different devices. If I understand correctly, your purpose is to switch from the back facing camera to the front facing. Please understand that these two different devices **may** handle this key differently

Comment: @AlexCohn: not neccessarily to switch, right now I'm working with the same camera. But yes, the main purpose is switching cameras. Also, I think you're wrong, the documentation doesn't say I *must* use a display surface. That's just a convenience helper. I don't need it in my app.

Comment: It's not a convenience helper. See [android.hardware.Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#startPreview()): **startPreview()**
*Starts capturing and drawing preview frames to the screen. Preview will not actually start until a surface is supplied with setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder) or setPreviewTexture(SurfaceTexture)*.

Comment: @AlexCohn: thank you, I've missed that part. Still, preview works  fine for me with no surface on 2 vastly different devices, one with Android 3.1 and one with 4.2.2. Anyway, can I set a dummy holder or texture that I won't use anywhere else?

Comment: Sure you can. On 3.0 and higher it is easier to achieve with setPreviewTexture(). There is a long list of <s>hacks</s> workarounds in _[this SO topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386025/android-camera-without-preview)_.

Comment: Anyways, Camera.release() may take time, and Camera.open() - even more time. But both these calls are blocking.

Comment: If you continue to see problems with switching camera, please post the logcat (including all camera messages coming from the MediaServer process), and disclose which device and ROM you are using.

Comment: @AlexCohn: `release` is blocking, but what about `stopPreview` call?

Comment: @AlexCohn: I have changed the question, please take a look if you can.

Comment: Isn't this the preview callback that causes the exception? `onPreviewFrame()` is not synchroneous, and it receives a Camera parameter that may become invalid when `Camera.release()` is performed. This could happen even if callbacks happen in the same thread. You can call `setPreviewCallback(null)`, and keep a global flag to discard callbacks after the camera is released.

Comment: @AlexCohn: good catch, but that is certainly not my case. I've edited my question to reflect the most recent debugging conclusion I've got: it is `releaseCamera()` alone that causes the problem. I don't have to call `open` for it to occur. Also, I never use the `Camera` parameter of the callback.

Comment: Tried `setPreviewCallback(null)`?

Comment: @AlexCohn: I took your advice (`setPreviewCallback(null)`), and all the problems I've been fighting for the past 2 days are gone! Please make this an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preview callback could cause this exception. `onPreviewFrame()` is not synchroneous, and it receives a **Camera** parameter that may become invalid when `Camera.release()` is performed. This could happen even if callbacks are not using a separate thread (highly recommended).

Before `release()`, call `setPreviewCallback(null)`, and keep a global flag to discard callbacks after the camera is released.

Comment: You recommend a separate thread for camera callbacks, did I get that right? How do I do that? By initializing the camera in a separate thread?

Comment: Yes, by `Camera.open()` from a _[separate event thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149964/best-use-of-handlerthread-over-other-similar-classes)_