# E/CameraService: Permission Denial: can't use the camera pid=9410, uid=10230 CameraFragment

Tags: android, camera, fragment

I am creating the code for Swipe Fragment Camera it is returning error E/CameraService: Permission Denial: can't use the camera pid=9410, uid=10230

Here is the CameraFragment.java

```
    // Native camera.
    private Camera mCamera;

    // View to display the camera output.
    private CameraPreview mPreview;

    // Reference to the containing view.
    private View mCameraView;

    /**
     * Default empty constructor.
     */
    public CameraFragment(){
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Static factory method
     * @param sectionNumber
     * @return
     */

    /**
     * OnCreateView fragment override
     * @param inflater
     * @param container
     * @param savedInstanceState
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        boolean opened = safeCameraOpenInView(view);

        if(!opened){
            Log.d("CameraGuide","Error, Camera failed to open");
            return view;
        }

        // Trap the capture button.
        Button captureButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // get an image from the camera
                        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                    }
                }
        );

        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Recommended "safe" way to open the camera.
     * @param view
     * @return
     */
    private boolean safeCameraOpenInView(View view) {
        boolean qOpened;
        releaseCameraAndPreview();
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mCameraView = view;
        qOpened = (mCamera != null);

        if(qOpened){
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity().getBaseContext(), mCamera,view);
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mPreview);
            mPreview.startCameraPreview();
        }
        return qOpened;
    }

    /**
     * Safe method for getting a camera instance.
     * @return
     */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseCameraAndPreview();
    }

    /**
     * Clear any existing preview / camera.
     */
    private void releaseCameraAndPreview() {

        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
        if(mPreview != null){
            mPreview.destroyDrawingCache();
            mPreview.mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Surface on which the camera projects it's capture results. This is derived both from Google's docs and the
     * excellent StackOverflow answer provided below.
     *
     * Reference / Credit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942378/android-camera-will-not-work-startpreview-fails
     */
    class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        // SurfaceHolder
        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;

        // Our Camera.
        private Camera mCamera;

        // Parent Context.
        private Context mContext;

        // Camera Sizing (For rotation, orientation changes)
        private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

        // List of supported preview sizes
        private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;

        // Flash modes supported by this camera
        private List<String> mSupportedFlashModes;

        // View holding this camera.
        private View mCameraView;

        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera, View cameraView) {
            super(context);

            // Capture the context
            mCameraView = cameraView;
            mContext = context;
            setCamera(camera);

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            mHolder.setKeepScreenOn(true);
            // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        /**
         * Begin the preview of the camera input.
         */
        public void startCameraPreview()
        {
            try{
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Extract supported preview and flash modes from the camera.
         * @param camera
         */
        private void setCamera(Camera camera)
        {
            // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942378/android-camera-will-not-work-startpreview-fails
            mCamera = camera;
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            mSupportedFlashModes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes();

            // Set the camera to Auto Flash mode.
            if (mSupportedFlashModes != null && mSupportedFlashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO)){
                Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            }

            requestLayout();
        }

        /**
         * The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
         * @param holder
         */
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Dispose of the camera preview.
         * @param holder
         */
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if (mCamera != null){
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }
        }

        /**
         * React to surface changed events
         * @param holder
         * @param format
         * @param w
         * @param h
         */
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
            // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

            if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
                // preview surface does not exist
                return;
            }

            // stop preview before making changes
            try {
                Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

                // Set the auto-focus mode to "continuous"
                parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

                // Preview size must exist.
                if(mPreviewSize != null) {
                    Camera.Size previewSize = mPreviewSize;
                    parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
                }

                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Calculate the measurements of the layout
         * @param widthMeasureSpec
         * @param heightMeasureSpec
         */
        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
        {
            // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942378/android-camera-will-not-work-startpreview-fails
            final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
            final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

            if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null){
                mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Update the layout based on rotation and orientation changes.
         * @param changed
         * @param left
         * @param top
         * @param right
         * @param bottom
         */
        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942378/android-camera-will-not-work-startpreview-fails
            if (changed) {
                final int width = right - left;
                final int height = bottom - top;

                int previewWidth = width;
                int previewHeight = height;

                if (mPreviewSize != null){
                    Display display = ((WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

                    switch (display.getRotation())
                    {
                        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                            previewWidth = mPreviewSize.height;
                            previewHeight = mPreviewSize.width;
                            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                            break;
                        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                            previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                            previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
                            break;
                        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                            previewWidth = mPreviewSize.height;
                            previewHeight = mPreviewSize.width;
                            break;
                        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                            previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                            previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
                            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
                            break;
                    }
                }

                final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
                mCameraView.layout(0, height - scaledChildHeight, width, height);
            }
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param sizes
         * @param width
         * @param height
         * @return
         */
        private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int width, int height)
        {
            // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942378/android-camera-will-not-work-startpreview-fails
            Camera.Size optimalSize = null;

            final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
            double targetRatio = (double) height / width;

            // Try to find a size match which suits the whole screen minus the menu on the left.
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes){

                if (size.height != width) continue;
                double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
                if (ratio <= targetRatio + ASPECT_TOLERANCE && ratio >= targetRatio - ASPECT_TOLERANCE){
                    optimalSize = size;
                }
            }

            // If we cannot find the one that matches the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement.
            if (optimalSize == null) {
                // TODO : Backup in case we don't get a size.
            }

            return optimalSize;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Picture Callback for handling a picture capture and saving it out to a file.
     */
    private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image retrieval failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();

                // Restart the camera preview.
                safeCameraOpenInView(mCameraView);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Used to return the camera File output.
     * @return
     */
    private File getOutputMediaFile(){

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "UltimateCameraGuideApp");

        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("Camera Guide", "Required media storage does not exist");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");

        DialogHelper.showDialog( "Success!","Your picture has been saved!",getActivity());

        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

SectionsPagerAdapater.class

```
public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context,FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a InboxFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new InboxFragment();
            case 1:
                return new CameraFragment();
            case 2:
                return new FeedsFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();
            case 1:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();
            case 2:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

This is my MainAcivity.class

```
// Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

This is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!-- Accessing Camera Hardware -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.Camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.Camera" />
```

with:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Also, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, you will need to [ask the user for this permission at runtime](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), as it is a `dangerous` permission.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when i open the app in my HTC One m8 the camera doesn't open the 2nd Fragment.

Comment: @SagarAtalatti: That is a separate problem. I recommend that you ask a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you explain **precisely** what "the camera doesn't open the 2nd Fragment" means, including a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem.