# CameraFragment does not open Camera in the defined Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-camera

This code is based on [UltimateAndroidCamera](https://github.com/rexstjohn/UltimateAndroidCameraGuide)

CameraFragment.class

```
public class CameraFragment extends BaseFragment {

    // Native camera.
    private Camera mCamera;

    // View to display the camera output.
    private CameraPreview mPreview;

    // Reference to the containing view.
    private View mCameraView;

    /**
     * Default empty constructor.
     */
    public CameraFragment(){
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Static factory method
     * @param sectionNumber
     * @return
     */

    /**
     * OnCreateView fragment override
     * @param inflater
     * @param container
     * @param savedInstanceState
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        boolean opened = safeCameraOpenInView(view);

        if(!opened){
            Log.d("CameraGuide","Error, Camera failed to open");
            return view;
        }

        // Trap the capture button.
        Button captureButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // get an image from the camera
                        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                    }
                }
        );

        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Recommended "safe" way to open the camera.
     * @param view
     * @return
     */
    private boolean safeCameraOpenInView(View view) {
        boolean qOpened;
        releaseCameraAndPreview();
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mCameraView = view;
        qOpened = (mCamera != null);

        if(qOpened){
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity().getBaseContext(), mCamera,view);
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mPreview);
            mPreview.startCameraPreview();
        }
        return qOpened;
    }

    /**
     * Safe method for getting a camera instance.
     * @return
     */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseCameraAndPreview();
    }

    /**
     * Clear any existing preview / camera.
     */
    private void releaseCameraAndPreview() {

        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
        if(mPreview != null){
            mPreview.destroyDrawingCache();
            mPreview.mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Surface on which the camera projects it's capture results. This is derived both from Google's docs and the
     * excellent StackOverflow answer provided below.
     *
     * Reference / Credit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942378/android-camera-will-not-work-startpreview-fails
     */
    class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        // SurfaceHolder
        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;

        // Our Camera.
        private Camera mCamera;

        // Parent Context.
        private Context mContext;

        // Camera Sizing (For rotation, orientation changes)
        private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

        // List of supported preview sizes
        private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;

        // Flash modes supported by this camera
        private List<String> mSupportedFlashModes;

        // View holding this camera.
        private View mCameraView;

        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera, View cameraView) {
            super(context);

            // Capture the context
            mCameraView = cameraView;
            mContext = context;
            setCamera(camera);

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            mHolder.setKeepScreenOn(true);
            // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        /**
         * Begin the preview of the camera input.
         */
        public void startCameraPreview()
        {
            try{
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Extract supported preview and flash modes from the camera.
         * @param camera
         */
        private void setCamera(Camera camera)
        {
            // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942378/android-camera-will-not-work-startpreview-fails
            mCamera = camera;
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            mSupportedFlashModes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes();

            // Set the camera to Auto Flash mode.
            if (mSupportedFlashModes != null && mSupportedFlashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO)){
                Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            }

            requestLayout();
        }

        /**
         * The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
         * @param holder
         */
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Dispose of the camera preview.
         * @param holder
         */
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if (mCamera != null){
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }
        }

        /**
         * React to surface changed events
         * @param holder
         * @param format
         * @param w
         * @param h
         */
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
            // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

            if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
                // preview surface does not exist
                return;
            }

            // stop preview before making changes
            try {
                Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

                // Set the auto-focus mode to "continuous"
                parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

                // Preview size must exist.
                if(mPreviewSize != null) {
                    Camera.Size previewSize = mPreviewSize;
                    parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
                }

                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Calculate the measurements of the layout
         * @param widthMeasureSpec
         * @param heightMeasureSpec
         */
        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
        {
            // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942378/android-camera-will-not-work-startpreview-fails
            final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
            final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

            if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null){
                mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Update the layout based on rotation and orientation changes.
         * @param changed
         * @param left
         * @param top
         * @param right
         * @param bottom
         */
        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942378/android-camera-will-not-work-startpreview-fails
            if (changed) {
                final int width = right - left;
                final int height = bottom - top;

                int previewWidth = width;
                int previewHeight = height;

                if (mPreviewSize != null){
                    Display display = ((WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

                    switch (display.getRotation())
                    {
                        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                            previewWidth = mPreviewSize.height;
                            previewHeight = mPreviewSize.width;
                            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                            break;
                        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                            previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                            previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
                            break;
                        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                            previewWidth = mPreviewSize.height;
                            previewHeight = mPreviewSize.width;
                            break;
                        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                            previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                            previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
                            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
                            break;
                    }
                }

                final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
                mCameraView.layout(0, height - scaledChildHeight, width, height);
            }
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param sizes
         * @param width
         * @param height
         * @return
         */
        private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int width, int height)
        {
            // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942378/android-camera-will-not-work-startpreview-fails
            Camera.Size optimalSize = null;

            final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
            double targetRatio = (double) height / width;

            // Try to find a size match which suits the whole screen minus the menu on the left.
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes){

                if (size.height != width) continue;
                double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
                if (ratio <= targetRatio + ASPECT_TOLERANCE && ratio >= targetRatio - ASPECT_TOLERANCE){
                    optimalSize = size;
                }
            }

            // If we cannot find the one that matches the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement.
            if (optimalSize == null) {
                // TODO : Backup in case we don't get a size.
            }

            return optimalSize;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Picture Callback for handling a picture capture and saving it out to a file.
     */
    private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image retrieval failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();

                // Restart the camera preview.
                safeCameraOpenInView(mCameraView);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Used to return the camera File output.
     * @return
     */
    private File getOutputMediaFile(){

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "UltimateCameraGuideApp");

        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("Camera Guide", "Required media storage does not exist");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");

        DialogHelper.showDialog( "Success!","Your picture has been saved!",getActivity());

        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

CameraFragment.class extends BaseFragment.class below is the BaseFragment code:

```
public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "ARG_SECTION_NUMBER";

    /**
     * Default empty constructor
     */
    public BaseFragment(){
        //
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * mFragment to allow an interaction in this mFragment to be communicated
     * to the mActivity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * mActivity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
        public void onFragmentInteraction(String id);
        public void onFragmentInteraction(int actionId);
    }
}
```

CameraActivity.class

```
// Storage for camera image URI components
    private final static String CAPTURED_PHOTO_PATH_KEY = "mCurrentPhotoPath";
    private final static String CAPTURED_PHOTO_URI_KEY = "mCapturedImageURI";

    // Required for camera operations in order to save the image file on resume.
    private String mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
            savedInstanceState.putString(CAPTURED_PHOTO_PATH_KEY, mCurrentPhotoPath);
        }
        if (mCapturedImageURI != null) {
            savedInstanceState.putString(CAPTURED_PHOTO_URI_KEY, mCapturedImageURI.toString());
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(CAPTURED_PHOTO_PATH_KEY)) {
            mCurrentPhotoPath = savedInstanceState.getString(CAPTURED_PHOTO_PATH_KEY);
        }
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(CAPTURED_PHOTO_URI_KEY)) {
            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString(CAPTURED_PHOTO_URI_KEY));
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /**
     * Getters and setters.
     */

    public String getCurrentPhotoPath() {
        return mCurrentPhotoPath;
    }

    public void setCurrentPhotoPath(String mCurrentPhotoPath) {
        this.mCurrentPhotoPath = mCurrentPhotoPath;
    }

    public Uri getCapturedImageURI() {
        return mCapturedImageURI;
    }

    public void setCapturedImageURI(Uri mCapturedImageURI) {
        this.mCapturedImageURI = mCapturedImageURI;
    }
}
```

SectionsPagerAdapater.class

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        protected Context mContext;

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context,FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a InboxFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new InboxFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new CameraFragment();
                case 2:
                    return new FeedsFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return mContext.getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();
                case 1:
                    return mContext.getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();
                case 2:
                    return mContext.getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

MainActvity.class calling the SectionsPagerAdapter.class

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    // private SmsPrefManager pref;
    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    SmsPrefManager pref;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this,
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

AndroidManifest.xml Permissions:

```
<!-- Accessing Camera Hardware -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location"/>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Layout XML fragment_camera

```
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/innerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_capture"
            android:text="@string/btn_cam"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The Logcat does not return any Runtime error regarding the app running on my device which is API23 and on my Emulator API19. Kindly help me resolve this issue have been reffering to a lot of Stackoverflow Queries but found no solution. Thank you in advance!