# Android Studio Gradle: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > No matching client found for package

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, build.gradle

I am trying to upgrade my google play services dependencies to 8.4.0 by following the example Google gives [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/appinvites/app/build.gradle), but I am getting the following error ('com.example.exampleapp' is a replacement for my app package name):

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.example.exampleapp'
```

Project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Module app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.exampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:3.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Fri Jan 01 08:23:56 CST 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

Any ideas as to why gradle can't recognize my own app package name?

---

**EDIT:**

Ok, I'm getting different errors this time.

Based on the link Shawn Thye provided, I added this to the bottom of app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and leaving everything else what I listed previously I got this error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
/Users/user/Documents/AndroidStudio/ExampleApp/app/build.gradle
Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/user/Documents/AndroidStudio/ExampleApp/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 0.921 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

and the Gradle console:

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/user/Documents/AndroidStudio/ExampleApp/app/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/user/Documents/AndroidStudio/ExampleApp/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.211 secs
```

So, then I changed gradle-wrapper.properties as requested to "gradle-2.10-all" and got this error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
google-services plugin could not detect any version for com.google.android.gms, default version: 8.3.0 will be used.
please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.
:clean
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72311Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportGridlayoutV72311Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library
:app:prepareComDigitsSdkAndroidDigits192Library
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk470Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidExoplayerExoplayerR152Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement830Library
:app:prepareComMapboxMapboxsdkMapboxAndroidSdk230Library
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTweetComposer102Library
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTweetUi180Library
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTwitter1110Library
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTwitterCore162Library
:app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric1310Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0, but version 8.3.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0, but version 8.3.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
:app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 5.724 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

And the Gradle console:

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
google-services plugin could not detect any version for com.google.android.gms, default version: 8.3.0 will be used.
please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:clean
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72311Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportGridlayoutV72311Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library
:app:prepareComDigitsSdkAndroidDigits192Library
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk470Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidExoplayerExoplayerR152Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement830Library
:app:prepareComMapboxMapboxsdkMapboxAndroidSdk230Library
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTweetComposer102Library
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTweetUi180Library
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTwitter1110Library
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTwitterCore162Library
:app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric1310Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0, but version 8.3.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0, but version 8.3.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
:app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.724 secs
```

It's asking for the google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file, which it is already, and it's asking me to run 8.3.0 again... which I will do since that's the only thing working right now...

Comment: How did you rename your project?

Comment: I haven't renamed or refactored my project since I created it.  In terms of the above code though, 'com.example.exampleapp' is a replacement for my actual app package name.

Comment: did you solve this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately not yet.  I reverted back to 8.3.0 for now...

Comment: Could you post the entire logcat? It seems like this is not the bottomline of the error you are receiving, there could be much more.

Comment: Any update? Ran into this as well

Comment: I reverted back to 8.3.0 and haven't had time to run it again with the new library.  I'll try again soon and post the entire logcat.

Comment: So sorry for the delay.  gerardnimo, I added the entire Gradle Console Log.  Thanks for your help, please let me know if that reveals anything else I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 172):

```
"client": [
{
  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "9:99999999:android:9ccdbb6c1ae659b8",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "[packagename]"
    }
  }
```

`package_name` must match what's in your manifest file. you can find the `google-services.json` file if you look in the example photo below.

[image]

Comment: To everybody, please check if you need separate google-services.json files. Mine had all the info for 2 product flavors, so I put it at the directory `/app/` and do not have to struggle with all that complicated folder structure.

Answer (score 100):

**Simple and easy*.* In my case it solved by as below

[image]

Make sure your pakage name in mainifests file same as your gradle's applicationId.

Comment: This was the real solution for me! Thanks Hiren.

Comment: yaap, since before i was change the package name in manifest only. Thaaankssssssssssssssss

Comment: Most well come Chris Brother and Zacharia Brother

Comment: google-services.json wasn't having the correct package name, in my case.

Comment: If my answer is helpful and true than please mark it as true

Comment: In my case another google-services.json file was hiding under the app\src\debug folder. Updating it as well as all the others solved the problem

Comment: Solved my problem

Comment: @Hiren Thank you very much bro  +1

Answer (score 36):

Happened to me when switching flavors.

Now you can also use the **google-services.json** with different flavors.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34364376/570168

Comment: This is the one to check if the above still didnt fix the issue. nice one @Lord Flash

Answer (score 22):

Solved the problem of getting an exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not
>   initialized in this process Make sure to call
>   FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

in FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()

Check that **package_name** exactly matches **applicationId**
1) **build.gradle**

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "build.gradle.exactly.matches.json"
...
}
```

---

should **exactly** match 
2) **google-services.json**

```
{
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "build.gradle.exactly.matches.json"
        ....
```

---

Answer (score 21):

This exact same error happened to me only when I tried to build my debug build type. The way I solved it was to change my `google-services.json` for my debug build type. 
My original field had a field called `client_id` and the value was `android:com.example.exampleapp`, and I just deleted the `android:` prefix and leave as `com.example.exampleapp` and after that my gradle build was successful.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

I've just added back the `android:` prefix in my `google-services.json` and it continued to work correctly. Not sure what happened exactly but I was able to solve my problem with the solution mentioned above.

Comment: I'm getting the same errors either way.  Thanks though!

Comment: change version from `2.8` to `2.10` in gradle wrapper, then `File -:> Invalidate cache/Restart`

Comment: So this is not exactly a answer. I am not downvoting it beacause of your efforts. But if you have a better answer, it will be a great help.

Comment: Excellent/ Package name was different in my manifest and google-services.json

Comment: excellent answers. I suspected as such based on the error from processGoogleDebugServices....

Comment: One follow-up question -- do you actually need to change anything within Google for this?

Answer (score 15):

For fixing:

> No matching client found for package name 'com.example.exampleapp:

You should get a valid `google-service.json` file for your package from [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In)

For fixing:

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available at
>   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0.:

You should move `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the end of your app `gradle.build` file. Something like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 10):

I meet the problem when using Firebase, i think different package cause the problem.
I solved by adding packeage of new app within Firebase Console, and download google-services.json again.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Open google-services.json in android studio 
we can see a json object, and contain following items in 'client' jsonarray

"client_id": "android:your package name",
"package_name": "your package name",

Please verify your package and proceed.

Answer (score 5):

I found success using this configuration:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'
//or use
//classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
```

and

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

using 8.40 Google Play services. Alpha5 & Alpha6 gave the same 2.8 error you had, regardless of the distributionUrl being 2.10

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me when my package name wasn't represented in the google-services.json file I downloaded.  Open your google-services.json file and make sure there is a client_info object that has a package name that corresponds to your manifests package name.

In googleservices.json:

```
"client": [
  {
    "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "my-app-id",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.me.android.test.myapp"
  }
```

and in your manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.me.android.test.myapp" >
```

You may need to recreate a new google-services.json for your project, which you can create here: https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=gcm

Answer (score 5):

your **google-services.json** package name must match your **build.gradle** applicationId (applicationId "your package name")

Answer (score 3):

If this happened to you after *renaming your application package name*, then you need to update the following:

1)**google-services.json** file in your application by looking up in the file for "package_name" attribute and update it with the new package name.

2)Update your application client Credentials in **Google Developers Console** by going to the `Credentials` and selecting your android client key then update the package name as well with the new one.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 3):

check that, in your "google-services.json" file your package_name is available or not

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem  and just easy solve it make sure the package name for package in mainfest tag inside manifest.xml file and the applicationId in application tag inside gradle app level file has the same package name

in manifest.xml

```
package="com.example.work"
```

in gradle app level

```
applicationId "com.example.work"
```

hope it help

Answer (score 3):

1)check the package name is the same in google-services.json file

2)make sure that no other project exist with same package name

3)make sure that there is internet access

4)try syncing project and running it again

Answer (score 2):

Add this in project gradle file

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think because your are using play-service 8.4.0

It required

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha5'
```

you may also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34806311/5793477).

Comment: That is giving me a different error:  
Error:(37, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:2.0.0-alpha5
Error:(38, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:2.0.0-alpha5
Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in...

Comment: @TangoJLabs no!, this is classpath, not complile library

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to check the `google-services.json` file and make sure `"package_name"` was correctly set to the package name of my android app. The auto generated services file had `.backend` appended to it in my case.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when my package name wasn't represented in the google-services.json file I downloaded. Open your google-services.json file and make sure there is a client_info object that has a package name that corresponds to your manifests package name.

Make sure the package name in your project **manifest** is exactly the same in **google-services.json** file

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just Android studio run 'Run as administrator' it will work

Or verify your package name on **google-services.json** file

Answer (score 0):

after studying above that package name in manifest file and application id in gradle build file should be same. my issue didn't resolved.

Actually your application id in gradle build file should be same as your package name in google-services.json file. if your google-services.json file has different package name. delete that app from google analytics or firebase console. and get a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify `build.gradle.`

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<packagename>"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Verify the package name.It can also cause error.

Answer (score 0):

Both times when you write the package name :
1. When you create a new project in Android Studio 
and
2. When you create a Configuration File

YOU should write it with lowercase letters - after changing to lowercase it works. If you don't want to waste time just go to you .json file and replace com.myname.MyAPPlicationnamE with com.myname.myapplicationname (for every match in the json file).

Answer (score 0):

if you run the other type of build(for example sign apk or etc), you must select app type of build then run the projects.

please seen the following image. for run this project we must select "app" in run configuration popup.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I just had to do

1. Click **Build**
2. Click **Make Project**

It all then went fine. I still have no clue what happened.