# Build tools update breaks my compile

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build-tools, android-studio-2.0

I updated Android Studio 2.0 Preview from 4 to 5 this morning. If I continue to build with:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
}
```

this will still compile successfully. But if I move up to -alpha5 I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
>    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:....\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\8.4.0\jars\classes.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: I am having the same problem. I am also using `com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha5`. Like you, I can go back to `alpha3` and it works fine.

Comment: I reported the issue here. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198904

Comment: Any luck? @ChadBingham

Comment: @gbhall No. Ill post an answer if i find anything out and Ill let you know. For now, just use `alpha3`.

Comment: @ChadBingham Yeah I had a similar problem which I posted about on SO, but deleted after I realised it was trivial and due to my setup. I was referencing a file to include in my build that I no longer had. On previous versions of Gradle it did not care, however alpha-5 it threw the same FileNotFoundException. I think alpha-5 may be more strict.

Comment: how to go back to alpha-3 then? I'm getting this error too and not sure how to get past it

Comment: @user1406716 In your projects (not app) build.gradle file, change the classpath which will have ``2.0.0-alpha5`` to ``2.0.0-alpha3``

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From now on, I think Google expects us to not use this:

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

But rather add the services you need specifically. Find a [list of them here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0'
```

Also, you need to apply play service plugin in **last line** of your application's gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Just tried it. Wohoo that works! Thanks man. Keeping up with all the different new ways Google wants you to do things is a nightmare.

Comment: When I try to add the line "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'"  I get the error "Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found."

Comment: But... if I DON'T include that line, this works! Thanks Shawn! You're a rock star!

Comment: Yes, they did it again. This change will help to avoid the 64k limit read the link Shawn sent.

Comment: Excellent answer. Looks like they are going to work a real fix this, but this seems like a really efficient workaround.

Comment: @KairisCharm you need to also add the services plug in dependency in the root gradle which 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha5'

Comment: @ChadBingham I think it better now, because google allow you to include by needs, and i found that gradle build was actually faster

Comment: @ShawnThye yeah, i agree. It put me below the dex limit and my instant run is much faster. I think this is more than a workaround, but a sufficient solution.

Comment: Actually, this solution worked, but now I have a new problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818026/android-preview-build-tools-alpha-5-wont-deploy-apk

Answer (score 7):

I [posted a bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198904) here. They came out with a fix very quickly. Now just use `alpha6`:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot this fixed my problem too :)