# google play services 8.4.0 - classes.jar not found - android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am getting this error when I Run or Debug the app but when I build or clean my project there are no errors. It sounds strange but I've wasted my 4-5 hours searching for this but nothing was helpful. 
Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Saeed Jassani\Downloads\AppName\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\8.4.0\jars\classes.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: same here. I have updated google repositories but still the problem is not solving.

Comment: yes... i also updated every possible thing but the problem persists.. If someone can help then it will be really helpful

Comment: I think the problem is with the project directory as it contains a space `C:\Users\Saeed Jassani\Downloads...` . Try moving your project in a different directory.

Comment: @SaeedJassani do not include play-services:8.4.0 from now on, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34806311/5793477)

Comment: Pls read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34806573/google-play-service-error

Comment: Thanks @ShawnThye ... your solution works

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can fix this by using alpha6:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean your project and add following dependencies in your project level build.gradle file

```
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'

    }
```

Comment: First of all, the gradle android plugin should be specified at the project-level **build.gradle** file.  Then, `google-services` dependency should be specified in the app's **build.gradle**.  Should they be two separate files?