# Android preview build tools alpha 5 won't deploy APK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build-tools, android-studio-2.0

Whenever I try to start an app, either by debugging or playing, after compiling with:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5'
}
```

I get the message:

> No local changes detected, not deploying APK.

I get this even when there most certainly are changes, so I am unable to push any new changes to the device without actually moving the APK to the device and installing it manually. I've tried unchecking the "Skip installation if APK has not changed" configuration option, but that does nothing to help.

Comment: Is Google bringing back the gool ol' Eclipse bugs?

Comment: Are you using version 2.0 preview 4 of Android Studio?

Comment: No, I upgraded to 5. I was using 4 up until yesterday.

Comment: @KairisCharm I have disabled Instant Run for now : )

Comment: Have you tried restarting everything? If that doesn't work, just disable instant run and wait for `Alpha6`. It should be out any hour now.

Comment: Nothing better than working with alpha software ;)

Comment: @ChadBingham yeah, fixed by changing to alpha6 and claening project

Comment: Not working for me, even if I try on a new phone. It does work for a debug version, but not for a release version.

Answer (score 0):

Change your dependancies to `apha6`

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
}
```