# Android: Error when creating build

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

**I got an error when creating build and error. I had already done to cross check is google play installed or not.  **

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.xyz'
```

**This is my project gradle file source code**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**This is my build.gradle(Module.App) source code**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990479/no-matching-client-found-for-package-name-google-analytics-multiple-productf

Comment: Have you generated `google json` and add it to your project app directory ?

Comment: Yes I added generated google json file in app directory @jaydroider

Comment: Yes @KenWolf I have try to implement on this way. But not working.

Comment: @JagjeetSingh is your `google sevices json` contains this package name `com.xyz` ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/34679411/4815718