# Using Firebase Cloud Service getting Error:AppProcessDebugGoogle Service- No matching client found for package name

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am Using Firebase Cloud Messaging for Push Notification.

I followed all instructions of official site and successfully added all requirements. But I am getting a Error and not able to find any solution.

My Error is:

```
  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processInmemoryDebugGoogleServices'.
  > No matching client found for package name 'in.voiceme.app.voiceme.inmemory'
```

where I added google-service.json see.

My Project structure Looking Like

[image]

I already added in dependencies:

```
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

added classpath:

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        *classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'*

        *classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'*

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
 }
```

My app based Build.Gradle

```
      apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.voiceme.app.voiceme"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        inmemory {
            applicationId "in.voiceme.app.voiceme.inmemory"
        }

        live {
            applicationId "in.voiceme.app.voiceme"
        }
     }
   }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can anyone give me solution about this Error?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/34679411/4815718

Comment: @qbix while that is indeed the likely cause, I won't vote to close until either Dinesh confirms or adds the app's build.grade to the question (so that we can confirm).

Comment: check i added my full build.gradle code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the "inmemory" build flavor uses a different package name (applicationId) than the others, you need to modify your `google-services.json` file or perhaps provide multiple copies of it.  The [documentation for the Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) describes the folder structure for different build types and flavors.

If you do not need different project settings for your apps build types and flavors, it might be possible to use a single file and add an entry to the `client` array in the file. The added entry would specify package name `in.voiceme.app.voiceme.inmemory`.  See the linked document for more details, specifically the section on *Processing the JSON File*.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34364376/4815718) to a related question will also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue thanks to `@qbix`

```
 for productFlavors 

    inmemory {
        applicationId "in.voiceme.app.voiceme.inmemory"
    }

 Need to create different `google-service.json` using firebase console 
 and copy this json file into `inmemory` package.
```

i found problem was different pakageName not found by google-service.json, json file stores pakageName when we create this from Firebase Console.

```
provide new `google-service.json` to inmemory package is solution for that issue. thanks again @qbix
```