# Android: Test Ads not displaying

Tags: android, admob

i am trying to add Ads to my current activity but the activity is not showing any **Ad** . i have also add internet permission to **Android Manifest.xml**

Here is my

**.Gradle File**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "sms.and.call.alert.flashlight.lpa.com.myapplication"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'

        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.0'
    }
```

This is **MainActivity**

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
                  // An example device ID
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(request);

    }
}
```

This is **MainActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="sms.and.call.alert.flashlight.lpa.com.myapplication.MainActivity">
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you need this: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the end of your app build.gradle instead of compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0' and you need to put the google-services.json file in the correct place

Comment: i have put the json file in app folder seems fine? but giving me error pugin with id not found

Comment: @KumailHussain you have to copy it in the app folder. Here the instructions for the plugin: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start#integrate_firebase_and_the_mobile_ads_sdk

Comment: yes copied it in app folder

Comment: @ShrenikShah i have mentioned that in the description i have added the permission too

Comment: Follow the link i provided you in the previous comment to check if you have added the plugin correctly

Comment: yes, i have exactly followed the tutorial but receiving error i have mentioned above

Comment: if you have followed exactly the tutorial why you have a different build.gradle file? the one you posted in the question it's not the same showing in the tutorial i linked you

Comment: because i was receiving error in plugin error "plugin with id not found" then changed the line to compile

Comment: also check whether your unit ID is for banner only. if it is for interstitial than it won't load ad into adView

Comment: but you need the plugin to let it work. Have you updated the google repository to the lastest version in the SDK manager? then retry using the plugin like the tutorial do

Comment: what's the exact error the compiler give you when you try to build with the plugin?

Comment: Error:(28, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\android\Downloads\Compressed\AndroidReceiveSMS\MyApplication\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: Ok, have you added the classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' in the project build.gradle dependency? check this if you dont know how to do it https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk

Comment: after adding it i receive error

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'sms.and.call.alert.flashlight.lpa.com.myapplication'

Comment: @KumailHussain have you re-added the plugin at the end of the gradle.build?

Comment: @KumailHussain and you should check that your applicationId value it's the same of your package tag in the manifest.

Comment: I've provided you with a more exhaustive answer below which could be usefull to many others. Hope you will be able to get it works ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Admob-Firebase initial configuration guide

***updated 10/04/2016*** - MM/dd/yyyy

**Step 1** : Be sure to have the latest version of Google Play Services and Google Repository
[image: SDK versions]

**Step 2** : Put the google-services.json in the app folder after you had created the project on Firebase console 
More Info:https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

**Step 3** : Set up your project level build.gradle as below.
 More Info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

**Step 4** : Setup your app level build.gradle as below:
 More info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start#integrate_firebase_and_the_mobile_ads_sdk

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your.package.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Step 5** : Add those permissions to the AndroidManifest if they are not present yet

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Moreover be sure that your package name in the AndroidManifest match the applicationId of you app build.gradle or you will get a compilation error.

**Step 6** : Continue to follow the Quick-Start tutorial and learn how to create Ad-Units to show ads on your views: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

**Step 7** : If you still have compile time problems, check those really usefull and common-case threads and examples: 
Manifest and applicationId problems: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37177173/2910520, 
Multiple flavors problems:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34990999/2910520
Google Admob examples:https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples

Comment: Thanks for help, following these steps lead me to display Ads :)

Comment: Finally!! i'm glad i helped you. Hope that those informations will be usefull to someone else too :)

Comment: I forgot I had to implement the proper network permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to load the Ad by calling:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
mAdView.loadAd(request);
```