# Android camera fails on APi 22(Lollipop) but work on all other versions

Tags: java, android, android-camera, camera-api

I Created a Custom Camera and it keeps failing at on Api 22 but works on all other versions. I have tried it on. Am using the depreciated Camera API because the minver is API 19. Been trying to fix the issue but can't seem to solve it. Kindly help out

This is the Camera Preview Class

```
public CameraPreview(Context context, android.hardware.Camera camera,int cameraType) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.camera = camera;
    this.cameraType=cameraType;
    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
//        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);




}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        setCameraDisplayOrientation((Activity) context,cameraType,camera);

        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("tag", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    if (holder == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        camera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("tag", "Error setting camera stop: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
//                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        setCameraDisplayOrientation((Activity) context,cameraType,camera);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("tag", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera.release();
}
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
                                               int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
            new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}
```

The Error i keep getting is on the Start Preview

```
8-14 11:18:00.115 4391-4391/com.customcamera E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.customcamera, PID: 4391
java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
    at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)
    at com.customcamera.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:45)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:580)
    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:176)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1970)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942378/android-camera-will-not-work-startpreview-fails) may help /

Comment: Okay so I managed to solve this, there was no problem with the Camera Preview, i didn't set the camera type to be opened.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution , there was no problem with the Camera Preview, i didn't set the camera type to be opened. But still dont understand why it didi throw errors when i texted on API 19 and & 22.